# I have not decrypt the same as Android code in Objective-C. Android code is here

Tags: android, objective-c

1. This is Android method for encryption and decryption.
2. And Objective-C code also be right here, but I did not get same response in both. Anyone can let me out from this problem.

---

```
public class EncriptionDecriptionUtils {
    private static byte[] nrlmEncription = { 0x77, 0x71, 0x72, 0x76, 0x52,
     0x76, 0x44, 0x56, 0x68, 0x66, 0x75, 0x68, 0x77, 0x4b, 0x6f, 0x7d };

    public String decriptionOfData(String data) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(nrlmEncription, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(data,         Base64.DEFAULT));
        return new String(decrypted);
    }
    public String encriptionOfData(String data) throws Exception {
       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
       final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(nrlmEncription, "AES");
       cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
       return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

---

```
#import "NSData+AES.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>


@implementation EncInfo

@end

@implementation NSData (AES)

#pragma mark - Public Methods

- (NSData*) EncryptAES
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) );
    NSString * strKey;
   [strKey getCString: keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    const unsigned char iv[] = { 0x77, 0x71, 0x72, 0x76, 0x52,
    0x76, 0x44, 0x56, 0x68, 0x66, 0x75, 0x68, 0x77, 0x4b, 0x6f, 0x7d };

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt,
                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 iv,
                                 kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                 nil,
                                 [self bytes], [self length],
                                 buffer, bufferSize,
                                 &numBytesEncrypted );

    if( result == kCCSuccess )
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer    length:numBytesEncrypted];
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed AES");
    }
    return nil;
    }

- (NSData *) DecryptAES
{
    char  keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) );
    NSString * strKey;
    [strKey getCString: keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:   NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCKeySizeAES128;
    void *buffer_decrypt = malloc(bufferSize);
    const unsigned char iv[] = { 0x77, 0x71, 0x72, 0x76, 0x52,
    0x76, 0x44, 0x56, 0x68, 0x66, 0x75, 0x68, 0x77, 0x4b, 0x6f, 0x7d };

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt , kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 iv, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                 nil,
                                 [self bytes], [self length],
                                 buffer_decrypt, bufferSize,
                                 &numBytesEncrypted );

    if( result == kCCSuccess )
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer_decrypt length:numBytesEncrypted];

    return nil;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on how you compared the responses, I notice two differences in your implementations:

- In the Android implementation you Base64 encode the result after encrypting and Base64 decode before decrypting. The Objective-C implementation doesn't contain Base64 encoding/decoding.
- The Objective-C implementation is configured with kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, while the Android implementation uses PKCS5Padding.